# Why was this question about one-click file-hosting closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

For a question on the gaming.stackexchange.com site, I wanted to upload a few files that can be useful as a solution to a technical problem with a game.

I know there are file-hosting services that offer one-click uploading, so I don't have to bother with registering - I just want to upload one zip and be done with it. The problem is, with many of these services the files expire after a while, and I couldn't quite put my finger on what services maintain the file indefinitely (at least, until they shut down) and have good reputation. So, I came here, and luckily for me I found a question *extremely* similar to what I've been looking for - with the exception that it wants a list and I want recommendations:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9151/list-of-free-one-click-hosting-that-never-expire-uploaded-files-stay-forever

I was thrilled - until I realize that the question was closed. I thought asking for recommendations is alright on this site, so could someone explain why was it closed? And perhaps it could be edited into a form in which it will be open? Since I find it very useful.

Also, I would certainly not consider it a duplicate of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/638/online-file-storage-services), which isn't concerned with one-click hosting.

Comment: you could try editing it into shape -- so in this case, perhaps, add more parameters to narrow it down so that it's not an infinitely growing list of opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took what you said up above (verbatim) which gives a little description into the problem and expanded on why the current options don't fit the bill.

Also the post has been re-opened, "un-wiki-fied" and a bounty has been attached.

I still think it needs work, so I hope the community helps to prevent it from turning into a list. But as it stands it has been re-opened.

Comment: Well it's certainly much better now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Various users may find recommendation questions palatable, but, yeah, depends on who has close votes on that front.

Otherwise, the question is just asking for a list. No qualifications, no parameters, nothing to set boundaries, and you have what will be a long list of one-liners with no reason as to why they're suggested.

Comment: It was closed by a moderator, so it didn't depend on what 3k users noticed it at the time. In any case, I proposed an edit that might give it a little more meat, hopefully it could get it re-opened.

Comment: @Oak It needs more reasoning. You just expanded what the OP meant by one click. It is still just a big list. There is no reason why the services listed (http://www.megaupload.com
http://www.mediafire.com
http://www.badongo.com) don't work for your purpose. Questions on alternatives are mainly for restrictions on the current app. Recommendation questions are welcome but the purpose must be specific and clear as to why the current solutions don't work.

Comment: we should try to whip this one into shape if Oak helps

Answer (score 3):

Asking for app recommendations is no longer on-topic on this site, and hasn't been for some time.

If you are looking for a recommendation for a web application, and *not* a web *site*, then [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) is the place to go. Do be sure to read their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), though, because they have stringent requirements for questions.